# Dynamic Queries using Couch_Potato

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchdb, couchpotato

The documentation for creating a fairly straightforward view is easy enough to find:

```
view :completed, :key => :name, :conditions => 'doc.completed === true'
```

How, though, does one construct a view with a condition created on the fly? For example, if I want to use a query along the lines of

```
doc.owner_id == my_var
```

Where my_var is set programatically.

Is this even possible? I'm very new to NoSQL so apologies if I'm making no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views in CouchDB are incrementally built / indexed as data is inserted / updated into that particular database.  So in order to take full advantage of the power behind views you won't want to dynamically query them.  You'll want to construct your views in such a way that you can efficiently access the data based on the expected usage patterns of the application.  In my experience it's not uncommon to have multiple views each giving you a different way to access / query the same data.  I find it helpful to think of CouchDB views as a way to systematically denormalize your documents.

On the other hand there are also ways to generalize your indexes in your views so you can use a single view for endless combinations of queries.

For example, you have an "articles" database, and each article document contains a list of tags.  If you want to set up a query to dynamically retrieve all articles tagged with a handful of tags, you could emit multiple entries to the view on the same document:

```
// this article is tagged with "tag1","tag2","tag3"
emit("tag1",doc._id);
emit("tag2",doc._id);
emit("tag3",doc._id);
....
```

Now you have a way to query: Give me all articles tagged with these words: ["tag1","tag2",etc]

For more info on how to query multiple keys see "Parameter -> keys" in the table of Querying Options here:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

One problem with the above example is it would produce duplicates if a single document was tagged with both or all of the tags you were querying for.  You can easily de-dupe the results of the view by using a CouchDB "List Function".  More info about list functions can be found here:

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html

Another way to construct views for even more robust "dynamic" access to the data would be to compose your indexes out of complex data types such as JavaScript arrays.  Also incorporating "range queries" can help.  So for example if you have a 3-item array in your index, but only have the first 2 values, you can set up a range query to pull all documents that match the first 2 items of the array.  Some useful info about that can be found here:

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html

Refer to the "startkey", and "endkey" options under "Querying Options" table here:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

It's good to know how CouchDB indexes itself.  It uses a "B+ tree" data structure:

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/btree.html

Keep this in mind when thinking about how to compose your indexes.  This has specific implications about how you need to construct your indexes.  For example, you can't expect to get good performance on a view if you query with a range on the first item in the array.  For example:

```
startkey = [a,1,2]
endkey = [z,1,2]
```

You'll get the performance you'd expect if your query is:

```
startkey = [1,2,a]
endkey = [1,2,z]
```

This, in more general terms, means that index order does matter when querying views.  Not just on basis of performance, but on basis of what documents will be returned.  If you index a document in a view with [1,2,3], you can't expect it to show up in query for index [3,2,1], [2,1,3], or any other combination.

In my experience, most data-access problems can be solved elegantly and efficiently with CouchDB and the basic tools it provides.  If / when your project needs true dynamic access to the data, I generally still use CouchDB for common data access needs, but I'll also integrate ElasticSearch using an ElasticSearch plugin which streams your data from CouchDB into ElasticSearch as it becomes available:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb

Comment: What an answer, thank you. This gives me plenty of food for thought besides my original problem.